# How to balance the cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

We have 30 hadoop prod nodes and they the cluster is unbalanced.

```
Datacenter: Hadoop
==================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                           Rack
UN  x.x.x.1  13.64 GB   1       0.0%   16e90f33-6f79-41e8-bd25-22e5eea6707b  RAC-1
UN  x.x.x.2  11.27 GB   1       0.0%   3a9da644-2587-42b3-9162-7fb504cfbf97  RAC-3
UN  x.x.x.3  10.76 GB   1       0.0%   e0b67015-bb37-466b-b837-17d758535a4d  RAC-1
UN  x.x.x.4  10.07 GB   1       0.0%   2110d060-3d6f-404a-8979-a4c98b1e63ae  RAC-1
UN  x.x.x.5  260.31 GB  1       0.0%   48da7d4d-f396-4d12-a481-c316b367194b  RAC-1
UN  x.x.x.6  17.32 GB   1       0.0%   45806806-5c84-4898-9835-9e0874a48ded  RAC-2
UN  x.x.x.7  7.66 GB    1       0.0%   2724dddf-011e-431f-8936-0dc576ee833e  RAC-2
UN  x.x.x.8  11.95 GB   1       0.0%   61e83114-32ad-4abe-b6bf-228792bcd0fa  RAC-2
UN  x.x.x.9  16.38 GB   1       0.0%   988ec834-c4e5-4170-9c04-c5a7d20b3094  RAC-3
UN  x.x.x.10  10.53 GB   1       0.0%   0b53cf24-541f-4e25-810b-7020e10817ee  RAC-3
UN  x.x.x.11  10.3 GB    1       0.0%   ae14518d-c1c2-4c21-998b-273e961cd1c0  RAC-2
UN  x.x.x.12  15.42 GB   1       0.0%   019f1a17-11c6-4a38-b7f9-658030fe0eac  RAC-2
UN  x.x.x.13  11.1 GB    1       0.0%   0cdabec3-95e2-4451-ba69-a659874fe300  RAC-2
UN  x.x.x.14  9.58 GB    1       0.0%   4c43064c-be29-4723-be2d-cd0e3cd92909  RAC-3
UN  x.x.x.15  11.73 GB   1       0.0%   cc469cee-1ca0-45a9-bfd0-c182b0727238  RAC-2
UN  x.x.x.16  9.55 GB    1       0.0%   0ccd790e-7d1c-4cc8-8ebb-9ec786ee9962  RAC-2
UN  x.x.x.17  9.44 GB    1       0.0%   3a60244e-8af9-45a4-988a-d5158fbe04e7  RAC-3
UN  x.x.x.18  11.44 GB   1       0.0%   0b7508e9-e06f-4532-841c-08047f6ebf35  RAC-3
UN  x.x.x.19  13.25 GB   1       0.0%   7648792b-9c92-45be-b82a-e171d21756d6  RAC-3
UN  x.x.x.20  256.81 GB  1       0.0%   92033ad7-d60f-4a89-9439-0af7e744a246  RAC-2
UN  x.x.x.21  10.03 GB   1       0.0%   e494a90f-64b1-4f84-94fa-b228a8ef3160  RAC-1
UN  x.x.x.22  9.32 GB    1       0.0%   64f9a2e4-2aab-408c-9d5f-5867ab26398c  RAC-3
UN  x.x.x.23  14.74 GB   1       0.0%   0ea50e73-b36c-44e9-934f-a92f14acbe23  RAC-1
UN  x.x.x.24  12.37 GB   1       0.0%   804927a6-d096-4b6e-92af-43ad13e10504  RAC-1
UN  x.x.x.24  258.85 GB  1       0.0%   7c1bc96c-4806-4216-bd6a-a28db4b528d1  RAC-3
UN  x.x.x.26  10.38 GB   1       0.0%   2932bae4-c656-4378-9570-0f79131fe3a8  RAC-2
UN  x.x.x.27  11.67 GB   1       0.0%   918bc253-40b6-4a56-ab4a-e50953ffb355  RAC-1
UN  x.x.x.28  8.17 GB    1       0.0%   bb302317-3671-4174-82b0-43f53c683f44  RAC-1
UN  x.x.x.29  10.57 GB   1       0.0%   ff4a1e2e-249b-44d7-b488-0acd99a6db86  RAC-1
UN  x.x.x.30  12.27 GB   1       0.0%   df75362f-24c0-4783-a03c-b2a578c0927d  RAC-3
```

Almost all the data is going to only 3 nodes(5,20 and 24) in the cluster. I cannot use vnodes because DSE hadoop nodes not support it.

I know we can use nodetool move  to rearrange the tokens but how to calculate the middle token?

How to balance it? how to calculate the tokens and move it?

Comment: It's been awhile since I've managed Cassandra clusters.  Do they still need periodic (manual) full compaction?  Have you been using the DataStax console tool for scheduling compaction on the nodes?

Comment: No, we are not using opscenter.

Comment: Traditionally (pre-vnodes) you could take the (reverse sorted) list of token boundaries (which range each node "Owns"), and subtract each from the from the previous to see how large each slice of the token space is.  Normally that should be balanced.  I tried doing that with the large hex values under the "Owns" column in your posting ... and it looks completely wrong to me.  So I have no idea what I'm looking at.

I'm also not familiar with Cassandra hosted on Hadoop.  Perhaps my knowledge of Cassandra is too obsolete to be of use here.

Comment: Those are not tokens. These are the tokens (-9223372036854775808,-8608480567731124088).

Comment: How distributed are your row keys / partition keys? If most of your data has the same partition key, you can end up with a similar distribution. If you are using CQL tables, the first column in the primary key is the partition key.

Comment: If only 3 nodes contains your data and you have an RF=3 you are almost surely using a fixed partition (row name) -- if so there is no way to rebalance your cluster

Comment: The rebalance button in OpsCenter is the standard strategy for this.  If you have already tried that, my guess would be that you have one Huge partition in nodes ending in 5, 20, and 24. You may want to consider changing your data model. EDIT: Noticed you're not using opsc center, ignore that part.

Comment: Could you post the output of `nodetool ring` this should show the distribution of tokens. You can use the documentation here to help you generate tokens: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configGenTokens_c.html